# AJAX call to Django View returns None

Tags: python, django, ajax

I trying to get data which I send with AJAX

> base.html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>

    function getAjaxResponse() {
      console.log('myAjax');
      $.getJSON('/ajax', { get_param: 'data' }, function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            console.log(key);
            console.log(val); 
        });
      });
    }

    $(function(){
      $("input[name='barcode']").change(function() {  
        var barcode = document.getElementById("id_barcode").value;
        $.ajax({
          type:'GET',
          url:`ajax/?variable=${barcode}`,
          headers: {'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
          success: function(response){
              console.log('success');
              console.log(barcode);
              setTimeout(getAjaxResponse, 3000);
          },
          error: function (response){
              console.log('error');
          }
        });              
      });     
    });            

  </script>
```

> urls.py

```
path('ajax/', views.ajaxBarcode, name='ajaxBarcode'),
```

> views.py

```
def ajaxBarcode(request):
    barcode = request.GET.get('variable')
    dict = {}
    if len(str(barcode)):
        dict['hint1'] = str(barcode)
    return JsonResponse(dict)
```

When I retrieve data in browser I always had hint1 and None.
But when I type in address line /ajax/?variable=115 I have response {"hint1": "115"}

Comment: `len(str(barcode))` is 4 and "truthy" when `barcode` is `None` -> `"None"` into the dict. Use `if barcode is not None`. You need to debug your JS to check why it is not passed.